# Plug-In to help filter internal traffic - GA4

Tags: google-analytics

We have many users at the company and many are working remotely. We are trying to filter out internal traffic with as little effort on the part of users.

They will not login, and so I believe the only somewhat reliable way is to somehow pass the parameter through a plugin without any action from the user.

Perhaps you can share alternative solutions?

Haven't tried anything yet aside from validating parameter value and filter functionality

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.